# How do I include a reverse relation that is not direct (goes through another resource) in django-tastypie?

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I have 3 models. Game, player and piece. A player is attached to a game and a piece is attached to a player. The relations are simple foreign keys.

When retrieving the game, I wish to also retrieve all of the pieces from all of the players and include them in the result.

```
class GameResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Game.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'game'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

class PlayerResource(ModelResource):
    game = fields.ForeignKey(GameResource, 'game')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Player.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'player'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

class PieceResource(ModelResource):
    player = fields.ForeignKey(PlayerResource, 'player')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Piece.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'piece'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

I have no idea how this is done. I originally changed dehydrate so that it simply does the right query, calls django serialize, and puts it in a new variable in the bundle. This seems like a bodge to me. The serialize of the queryset was also serialized again by tastypie causing it to escape quotation characters (urgh).

Comment: Cant answer as havn't got enough reputation. Solution is to simply add the tomany field on both the game and player and set full=true on both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
class GameResource(ModelResource):
    players = fields.ToManyField('blokus.api.PlayerResource', 'player_set', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Game.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'game'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()


class PlayerResource(ModelResource):
    game = fields.ForeignKey(GameResource, 'game')
    pieces = fields.ToManyField('blokus.api.PieceResource', 'piece_set', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Player.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'player'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()


class PieceResource(ModelResource):
    player = fields.ForeignKey(PlayerResource, 'player')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Piece.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'piece'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()
```